# Create row in table A for each distinct value in table B

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct, sql-insert

I have table A which has ID and proposalID. Table B has a proposalID as well. What I want to do is for each distinct proposalID in table B, I want to create a new row in table A with the same proposalID and a new ID.

So table A has these distinct proposalIDs:

```
94CAEF39-855B-4B5C-9534-9D4AD0A75FC8
C1D87317-7028-4F69-91D4-FFFBB35E7ACD
807D7733-5CCF-486F-81E5-FFF153307C22
521E22E2-511E-46F2-AA46-FFF832367A9E
```

What i want table B to have now is:

```
ID: new uniqueidentifier, proposalID: 94CAEF39-855B-4B5C-9534-9D4AD0A75FC8
ID: new uniqueidentifier, proposalID: C1D87317-7028-4F69-91D4-FFFBB35E7ACD
ID: new uniqueidentifier, proposalID: 807D7733-5CCF-486F-81E5-FFF153307C22
ID: new uniqueidentifier, proposalID: 521E22E2-511E-46F2-AA46-FFF832367A9E
```

I'm still learning sql and don't know how to approach this. I know how to get all the distinct proposalIDs but after that i don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
insert into A(id, proposal)
    select uuid(), proposal
    from (select distinct proposal
          from b
         ) b;
```

However, wouldn't it be simpler to use an auto-incrementing id for table `A`?  Then the `id` would set itself when you insert a new value.